# How to add flash video(swf) in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, flash

Hi I want to insert flash object in my Asp.net page.I just googled it but found results to create specific object in the page script.Is there any additional UI component available with Simple Drag and drop interface for flash file.

Comment: what about js wrapper swfobject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use some third party control...

check the links

[Flash Control for ASP.NET](http://www.flash-control.net/)

[FlashMovie WebControl](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/AspNetFlashMovieControl.aspx)

[SWFObject Server Control for ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/swfobject_server_control.aspx)